# Apply a script by looping through multiple files in a directory and copy the changes back to every corresponding file

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to apply the below script to every file in the `Weather` directory and copy the changes back to the same csv file (`Bladen.csv` in this case).

```
Bladen <- read.csv("C:/Users//Desktop/Weather/Bladen.csv",header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
Bladen <- Bladen[,c(1,6,11,17,18,19)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to update each file in your directory by adding the same column to each file and writing the file back to the same directory.

```
setwd(set_your_path)
filenames <- list.files()
lapply(filenames, function(i){
  Bladen = read.csv(i, sep = ",", header = TRUE, na.strings = c("NA","N/A","null",""," "))
  Bladen<- Bladen[, c(1,6,11,17,18,19)]
  write.csv(Bladen, i, sep = ",")
})
```

Comment: Thanks @LuísTelles. I got it. I edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
setwd('/adress/to/the/path')
files <- dir()

for(i in files){
  Bladen <- read.csv(i, header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
  Bladen <- Bladen[,c(1,6,11,17,18,19)]
  write.csv(Bladen, i)
}
```

Please tell me if it works for you.